# Ajax method in jquery using PHP as backend

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I have a script file where the ajax method has been implemented, which adds a record to a form ...and then i have a php file which serves as the backend. What I am trying to say is we dint declare the record variable in php, we only declared it in jquery part. But how did we actually accessed it using

```
$record = json_decode($_POST['record']);
```

What is json_decode and json_stringify in the script file.

main.js

```
$add_form.submit(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        var fields = ['id', 'name', 'subject', 'theory', 'practical'];
        var record = {};

        for (var index in fields) {

            var field = fields[index];

            if (field == 'id' || field == 'theory' || field == 'practical')
                record[field] = parseInt( $('input#add_'+field).val() );

            else
                record[field] = $('input#add_'+field).val();

        }


        record.total = record.theory + record.practical;



        $.ajax({
            url: '/ab_batch/practice/db/action.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                action: 'ajaxAddRecord',
                record: JSON.stringify(record)
            },

            success: function(result) {

                if ( 'true' == result.trim() ) {

                    $add_modal.find('.ajax_add_result').text('Student Record Added...').css({
                        color: 'green',
                        display: 'block'
                    }).fadeOut(2500);



                }
                else {
                    $add_modal.find('.ajax_add_result').text('Error Adding Student Record!').css({
                        color: 'red',
                        display: 'block'
                    }).fadeOut(2500);
                }

            },

            error: function() {}

        });


    });
```

action.php

```
switch ($action) {
case 'ajaxAddRecord':

        $record = json_decode($_POST['record']);
        print ( $student->addRecord($record) ) ? 'true' : 'false' ;

        break;
}
```

Comment: Everything seems okay ! did you get any errors ?!! what's really the problem ?

Comment: You want someone to explain to you how this code works?

Comment: Yes....I want somebody to explain me some part of the code...we dint declare the record variable in php, we only declared it in jquery part. But how did we actually accessed it using

$record = json_decode($_POST['record']);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The action variable is declared (created) in main.js. You're right.
It is an object which is then used and filled with values.

The `$.ajax({` code block sends it *stringified* to action.php.
*"stringified"* means converted to a string.
It has to be done to send it to the server-side PHP because an object (or an array) can't be sent directly without converting it to a string.

Then this string, received has `$_POST['record']`, has to be "decoded" to access the values.
This is what `json_decode` does... It creates an array with it.

Google theses keywords for more:
`jQuery object`
`JSON.stringify()`
`json_decode()`
`PHP array`
`Ajax example tutorial`

Comment: Okay...so the data field in the ajax method is the part that we are sending to action.php or the part that we recieved from action.php ??

Comment: Yes, exactly `data` is the part sent. And the `success` is the "callback" actions to do with the result from action.php