# How to get jquery ajax response data and display in codeigniter view html div id

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am new in codeigniter.

I want to display data in codeigniter view div id from ajax on window load.

**View.php**

```
<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript'>
$(window).load(function() 
{
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>colleges/index",       
       success: function(server_response
       {
           if(server_response == 'success')
           {
              $("#fillgrid").html(server_response); 
           } 
           else{
              alert('Not OKay');
           }
                      }
   });   //$.ajax ends here
});
</script>
```

Comment: What is the problem here? Are you stuck somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I added explanations directly in code:

```
$(window).load(function() 
{
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>colleges/index",       
       success: function(server_response)           // Added missing parenthesis
       {
           if(server_response == 'success')         // You already are in the success callback.
           {                                        
              $("#fillgrid").html(server_response); 
           } 
           else{
              alert('Not OKay');
           }
                      }
   });   //$.ajax ends here
});
```

Function simplifed:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>colleges/index",       
    success: function(server_response){
        $("#fillgrid").html(server_response); 
    },
    error: function(){
        alert('Not Okay');
    }
});   //$.ajax ends here
```

Don't place an Ajax function inside a `.load()` method !
[`.load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) is a jQuery shorthand for [`.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).
So it's one or the other... But not both.

Using `.load()`, it would be:

```
$("#fillgrid").load("<?php echo base_url(); ?>colleges/index");
```

Comment: In my model.php

public function get_all_college()
{   
   $this->db->order_by("id","DESC");
   $query = $this->db->get("tbl_colleges");

   return $query->result_array();        
}

In my controller.php

public function index()
{
   $list['college'] = $this->Colleges_model->get_all_college();     

   $this->load->view('header');
   $this->load->view('Colleges/all_colleges', $list);
   $this->load->view('footer');
}

It is right above code.

Comment: Ajax `server_response` contains the html produced. I'm not really used to model/controller/view framework... You have to make something to echo the result.

Comment: «It is right above code.» It does'nt matter where the PHP script is versus the jQuery script. PHP executes server-side... And jQuery executes on client-side, "long" after the PHP. ;) So here, you produce a page that recalls PHP again... I hope you don't mke the common error : a page that calls itself... The ajax called content should be another PHP script than the one of the main page.

Comment: Here is a previous answer I made to "explain" things about a working Ajax example... May be usfefull to you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38187894/ajax-method-in-jquery-using-php-as-backend/38188284#38188284

Comment: Hey!! I just saw that!!! You placed an Ajax call inside a `.load()` method ?!?! I edited my answer.